# How can I see the invoice in Odoo 9 - Point Of Sale

Tags: report, odoo-9, invoice, point-of-sale

I have installed **odoo 9**

And I am able to see the invoices and reports for the purchases as well as sales. But in the case od **point of sales**, how can we see the invoices and reports.

I would like to see the **invoices/reports** as POS login, as well as the administrator after the validation/payment, is done.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you take an order in Odoo POS, select a customer and register a payment on the order. Go to Point Of Sale -> Orders and you will see your order as having an Invoiced state. Click print on the menu on the top and you can print the invoice and the receipt